# WiX c++ :: Proper way of using dll entries in deferred ca

Tags: c++, wix, custom-action, dllexport

I have a project with 2 different .cpp`s.
MyProj consists of MyCPP1 and MyCPP2
MyCPP1 contains different functions to be executed from msi using wix.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) UINT __stdcall MyCAFunction(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
    TCHAR name[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    DWORD nameLen = MAX_PATH;
    TCHAR keydir[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    DWORD keydirLen = MAX_PATH;

    MsiGetProperty (hInstall, L"Val1", name, &nameLen);
    MsiGetProperty (hInstall, L"Val2", keydir, &keydirLen);
}
```

and the wix code is:

```
<CustomAction Id="MyCA.Props" Return="check" Property="MyCA" value="Val1=[LogonUser];Val2=[INSTALLDIR]"/>
<CustomAction Id="MyCA" Return="check" Execute="deferred" BinaryKey="Binary1" DllEntry="_MyCAFunction@4" HideTarget="no" />
<Binary Id="Binary1" SourceFile="$(var.ConfDir)MyProj.dll" />
```

Well... so i have an error:

> Error 1723: A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run.

What way i need to dig?

I have some thoughts in the way of CA types... such as the basic type of CA with FileKey reference is 17. but my CA type is 1041 (Orca helps). Could it be the issue of my problem?

I've checked the version with diferent types of CA. its just coz of the parameters of CA (just deleting Execute="deferred" change type from 1041 to 17 (standart type). THe last thing of solving this ussue is the dll. I'll see it today... any sujestions?

Tried different ways of building dll's. Works just the dll, built by the example project of C++ Wix Custom Action Project. I compared 3 or 4 different projects. By props, by links, by external dependancies... Cannot find the issue... Help me...

Comment: Make sure you are statically linking the runtime when building your DLL, so that it does not have external dependencies that may not be present at install time.

Comment: @K-ballo: I've closed all dependences except kernel, rebuilt dll into MD... rewrote the usage of entry point from MyCAFunction into _MyCAFunction@4... I've looked in orca, in dependance walker... all seems to be allright...but it doesn't work at all... the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the names of the functions exported from your DLL.

To do it, run [`dumpbin`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429/en-us) utility on your DLL with `/exports` flag.

Comment: I used to use Dependancy Walker. I know about such an issue.. its not my case...but thx, not so much answers on my post...

Comment: What does verbose installation log say? It can give you a hint. `msiexec /i product.msi /lv*x install.log`.

Comment: Can you load this DLL from another program? Write a simple program and just load it with `LoadLibrary`. Try to execute the function itself.

Comment: Another problem that can be here is unicode/non-unicode conflict. Are you sure `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` are defined? Additionally you use `TCHAR` for variables and add `L` prefix to string, you better use `TEXT()` macro which seamlessly handles non-/Unicode builds.

Comment: Plus *deferred* custom actions do not have access to *all* the properties, only `CustomActionData` property is available. For more details see [Obtaining Context Information for Deferred Execution Custom Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).